# How can i find one derived class implementation when i have IEnumerable<T> from Ninject binding

Tags: c#, .net, ninject

I have a  base class that implements an interface member as an abstract method. There are a few derived classes that override this abstract method. I have Ninject DI in place and  Kernel will give an array of `T(IEnumerable<T>)`. How can i call one specific derived class implementation using this `IEnumerable<T>`.

Here is some sample code

This is my interface

```
 public interface ICreateBatch
 {
    int CreateBatch();
 }
```

This is my base class with Interface implementation

```
public abstract class CreateBatchBase:ICreateBatch
{
    public abstract int CreateBatch();
}
```

Here is one of the derived class implementation

```
public class CreateDerived1Batch:CreateBatchBase
{
    public override int CreateBatch()
    {
        //Derived one implementation
    }
}

public class CreateDerived2Batch:CreateBatchBase
{
    public override int CreateBatch()
    {
        //Derived two implementation
    }
}
```

Ninject is giving me an IEnumerable. How can i specifically call CreateBatch() from CreateDerived1Batch?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You should provide some code.

Comment: See [Dependency Injection Unity - Conditional resolving](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32415954/) and [Unity: Conditional resolving](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26608271/). Although these examples use Unity instead of Ninject, they are based on [design patterns](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns) so they will work with any DI container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the normal way in this case is to use contextual binding (see https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding). E.g. if you bind your interface like this:

```
kernel.Bind<ICreateBatch>().To<CreateDerived1Batch>().WhenInjectedInto(typeof(TypeDependingOn1);
kernel.Bind<ICreateBatch>().To<CreateDerived2Batch>().WhenInjectedInto(typeof(TypeDependingOn2);
```

the right `ICreateBatch` should be injected into `TypeDependingOn1` and `TypeDependingOn2`respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ extension method `OfType<T>` to filter only the items that are of a given type:

```
collection.OfType<Derived>().Method();
```

Comment: As correct as the answer is, this goes against the principles of DI.
You should not reference specific implementations outside of DI configuration.